# "ion-infinite-scroll" dentro de un div o contenedor con un tamaño fijo

Tags: angular, ionic, scroll

Estoy intentado insertar un "ion-infinite-scroll" dentro de un "div" 
Una lista lateral que se recargue al desplazar el scroll, el problema es que todo lo que veo, es para hacerlo en el contenedor completo, o que llegue hasta el final de la aplicacion,
Alguien sabe como se podria hacer[image: in]

Lo que quiero es sustituir el paginado por un infiniti-scroll
He probado cargando la lista desde un componente distinto, poniendo tamaño al col que contiene la lista , agregando un scroll e insertando la lista dentro pero captura el evento del llegar al final del ion-content
gracias

Comment: puedes usar esta libreria https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll

Comment: Al final para solucionarlo, cree un componente nuevo, y en el componente dentro de un ion-componet crear el list y se visualiza sin problemas